# TYPO3 7.6, content preview in backend

Tags: content-management-system, typo3

Is it possible to render frontend content view in the backend? I want to substitute typical backend previews of content elements with their frontend views. I know how to register a tt_content_drawItem Hook class in `$GLOBALS`. In my custom Hook I would like to render content elements, return rendered content in $itemContent variable.

It seems that to solve this problem I need to somehow set frontend controller (`$GLOBALS['tsfe']`?). I've tried using `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\FrontendSimulatorUtility`.

Answer (score 2):

You should never fiddle around with getting TSFE running in the backend. That will just not really work!

As a solution, use the mentioned hook or check out that feature https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/7.5/Feature-69459-ShowTt_contentPreviewInPageModuleViaFluid.html and return a simplified rendering!

Comment: _You should never fiddle around with getting TSFE running in the
backend. That will just not really work!_
Wish I had known this yesterday, would've saved me couple of hours. Do you think it is possible to achieve frontend view using hook?

Comment: no FE will currently work, no matter if a hook or full TSFE. just use a simplified fluid template or use some magic with iframes and call the real Frontend